# Remove space between grid rows (CSS)

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have some code (using TailwindCSS) that sets up a simple two column grid. The image then spans 2 rows.

```
  <div class="bg-purple-300 container mx-auto">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <h1 class="text-7xl text-black">Hello world!</h1>
    <img src="../public/images/Filip.jpg" class="row-span-2" />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque
      lobortis eget ex ut semper. Suspendisse vel hendrerit tortor, ut
      imperdiet metus. Vivamus sed nunc bibendum libero tincidunt luctus vel
      a libero. Donec sit amet pellentesque quam. Interdum et malesuada
      fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In sodales est id lectus
      laoreet vehicula. Curabitur eget sodales quam. Curabitur eu metus
      lectus. Aliquam maximus, dolor at vulputate molestie, mi erat commodo
      purus, id pharetra lorem nisi in massa.1
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like there to be **zero space** between the title and the paragraph. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `row-span-3` for image

Comment: Interesting — why does that work?

Comment: Is there any way to keep the grid with 2 columns and to make it work by allocating the space differently?

Answer (score -1):

Use 3 rows for the image and the last row will consume that space and you won't notice any difference with a 2 rows configuration.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="bg-purple-300 container mx-auto">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
    <h1 class="text-7xl text-black">Hello world!</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/400/400" class="row-span-3" >
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque
      lobortis eget ex ut semper. Suspendisse vel hendrerit tortor, ut
      imperdiet metus. Vivamus sed nunc bibendum libero tincidunt luctus vel
      a libero. Donec sit amet pellentesque quam. Interdum et malesuada
      fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In sodales est id lectus
      laoreet vehicula. Curabitur eget sodales quam. Curabitur eu metus
      lectus. Aliquam maximus, dolor at vulputate molestie, mi erat commodo
      purus, id pharetra lorem nisi in massa.1
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation why 3 rows is working and 2 not.

Comment: @Michel I already gave the explanation ...